# Python BMI formula

Tags: python

I'm in process of learning Python 3. I want to make a simple BMI calculator, but i get wrong results.

```
weight = float(input("Your weight: "))
height = float(input("Your height: "))
bmi = weight/height**2
print("Your BMI:", bmi)
```

For the 169cm height and 50kg weight i get **0.001750639**, not **17.50639**. What am i doing wrong?
I've been searched for already maked BMI calculators, but the formula was the same i use.

Comment: You should use meters, not cm. `50/1.69**2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BMI = weight(kg) / height(m)
It seems like you're using 169cm
so it should be

```py
weight = float(input("Your weight in kg: "))
height = float(input("Your height in cm: "))
bmi = weight/(height / 100)**2
print("Your BMI:", bmi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations matters:

```
>>> 169/50**2
0.0676
>>> (169/50)**2
11.424399999999999
```

Comment: It's not an order of operations problem, it's a units of measure problem. as @busybear commented

Comment: No, i get 0.0875319492. 
and the formula is Weight/Height^2, not height/weight**2

Answer (score 0):

actually you enter the height in cm ,but but this formula you have to enter the height in meters

```
weight = float(input("Your weight: "))
height = float(input("Your height: "))
bmi = weight/(height**2)
print("Your BMI:", bmi)
```

weight = 50 height=1.69 meters
output

```
 Your weight: 50
 Your height: 1.69
 Your BMI: 17.506389832288786
```

else please convert your cm to meters but dividing 100 the height value

```
weight = float(input("Your weight: "))
height = float(input("Your height: "))
bmi = weight/((height/100)**2)
print("Your BMI:", bmi)
```

output

```
Your weight: 50
Your height: 169
Your BMI: 17.506389832288786
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your program using the proper units of measure:

```
weight = float(input("Your weight in kg: "))
height = float(input("Your height in cm: "))
height /= 100; # convert to meters
bmi = weight/height**2
print("Your BMI:", bmi)
```